# Using maybe for pattern-matching of list renders error

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, option-type

How should i use the `Just` constructor  when decomposing a pattern?
 
**E.G:**
 If my pattern is :   `(x1,x2,x3,....xn)`  i will have to enclose  each element of the pattern with its `Just`?

**My problem :** i am trying to implement the Init function "safely".
Do i have to use the `Just`for the tail and for the head too in the second line?

```
safeInit::[a]->Maybe [a]
safeInit (x:xs)=x: safeInit (Just xs) #Just x : safeInit Just xs ?
safeInit [x,y]=Just [x]
safeInit _ =Nothing
```

Comment: Use `safeInit (x:xs) = Just (init (x:xs))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- you make a call with as input a `Maybe [a]`; and
- your first pattern contains a (strict) superset then the second, so the second one will *never* fire.

For the first problem, the culprit is in the line:

```
safeInit (x:xs) = x: safeInit (Just xs)
```

Here `safeInit`, expects a list (type `[a]`), but you wrap the list in the `Just` constructor, hence you pass it a `Maybe [a]` value, and the `safeInit` can not handle this. So we can rewrite it to:

```
safeInit (x:xs) = x : safeInit xs
```

This will however *not* solve the problem, since now we call the "cons" (`:`) on an `a`, and `Maybe [a]`, and again, the function can not handle this. We will first have to inspect whether the recursive call produces a `safeInit`, and then prepend the `x` and rewrap it in a `Just`, we can do this with an `fmap`:

```
safeInit (x:xs) = fmap (x:) (safeInit xs)
```

For the second problem, we can rearrange the clauses:

```
safeInit :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeInit [x, _] = Just [x]
safeInit (x:xs) = fmap (x:) (safeInit xs)
safeInit [] = Nothing
```

Nevertheless there are still problems with this approach: it is rather inefficient, since we unwrap and wrap the `Just` element for all elements (except the last one), given that is not optimized. Furthermore in case we process an infinite list, we will get stuck in an infinite loop. We can improve it, by using an inner function, that calculates the `init` given we know for sure that that `init` is valid. For example:

```
safeInit :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeInit (x:xs) = Just (go x xs)
    where go _ [] = []
          go x (x2:xs) = x : go x2 xs
safeInit [] = Nothing
```

Comment: But are you not altering the initial list that way?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: you can not alter anything in Haskell, all variables are immutable. In what way do you think I am altering the initial list?

Comment: No you are not altering i thought you are appending the x to the xs...you were just decomposing further on with "x2".My bad sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it depends on what semantics you want. In case of `init`, once you've found any element at all, you know the result will actually be `Just` anyway, namely, `Just init_xs`. You then want to prepend the current `x` to the included list, not changing anything about the `Just`. The easiest way to do that is to use `Maybe`'s `Functor` instance:

```
safeInit (x:xs) = (x:) <$> safeInit xs
```

Note however that this only works if you put in an extra base case, and the clause must go *before* the generic cons one:

```
safeInit :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
safeInit [_] = Just []
safeInit (x:xs) = (x:) <$> safeInit xs
safeInit []  = Nothing
```

An alternative that's perhaps easier to understand is to pattern-match on the recursive result:

```
safeInit (x:xs) = case safeInit xs of
      Just init_xs -> Just $ x : init_xs
      Nothing -> Just []
safeInit [] = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Elmex80s's suggestion,

```
safeInit :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
safeInit [] = Nothing
safeInit xs = Just (init xs)
```

Comment: I did not want to use out of the box methods.But thank you anyway.